# How to write Fibonacci of as sum of smaller terms?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Lets say F(n) as Nth fibonacci term .Then can we easily see that F(n1+n2+n3+n4...+nt) can be written as sum of a*F(n1)+b*F(n2)+c*F(n3)... +x*F(nt)  where a, b and c .... x are base Fibonacci terms (F(0) And F(1)) since if we proceed backwards from F(n1+n2+n3... + nt) by writing this as sum of previous terms  ,we will encounter F(n1), F(n2), F(n3) ... and F(nt) . So how to find a , b and c coefficients of terms ?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It appears to be related to an ongoing competition:  https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: https://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ExperimentationCR/Lessons/Fibonacci/FibonacciII/fibonacci2.shtml , i was reading properties of fibonacci numbers , i was generalizing  whether fibonacci number can written as sum of its constituents

Comment: I don't know about an analytical solution but numerically you can turn this into a minimisation problem on a computer by finding the best solution to $aF(n_1) + bF(n_2) + cF(n_3) - F(n_1 + n_2 + n_3)) = 0$ in 3 dimensional space governed by the variables $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: The standard relation is $F(m+n)=aF(m)+bF(n)$ where $a=F(n+1),b=F(m-1)$.

Comment: People have been posting this (or similar) questions on this site ever since the codechef challenge appeared.  I think it should be on hold until the contest ends.

Comment: @lulu when the contest ends ?, i don't think this is related to that ,

Comment: @almagest but can F(n+1) and F(m-1) be written as sum of base F(0) and F(1) ?

Comment: @Nick What do you mean? $F(0)=0,F(1)=1$, so $F(n+1)=F(n+1)F(1)+kF(0)$ for any $k$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).